# How to read BMP file in C?

Tags: c, image, file, fread, bmp

I am trying to consult the basic information of a BMP. For that, I built a struct for the file header and another for the image header. Referring to a BMP table of values ​​(http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm), I read the values ​​and validated as specified. However, only the bfType is read correctly and other values ​​are filled in with wrong information. **On my computer, `sizeof(int) = 4`**

Structs:

```
typedef struct BmpFileHeader {
   char bfType[2];
   unsigned int bfSize;
   unsigned short int __bfReserved1;
   unsigned short int __bfReserved2;
   unsigned long int bfOffBits;
} BMPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct BmpImageHeader {
   unsigned int biSize;
   int biWidth;
   int biHeight;
   unsigned short int biPlanes;
   unsigned short int biBitCount;
   unsigned int biCompression;
   unsigned int biSizeImage;
   int biXPelsPerMeter;
   int biYPelPerMeter;
   unsigned int biClrUsed;
   unsigned int biClrImportant;  
} BMPIMAGEHEADER;
```

Print functions:

```
void printFileHeader(BMPFILEHEADER fileHeader) {
   printf("\nType: %c%c.\n", fileHeader.bfType[0],fileHeader.bfType[1]);
   printf("Size: %d.\n", fileHeader.bfSize);
   printf("Verify (Must be 0 0): %d %d.\n");
   printf("Offset : %d.\n", fileHeader.bfOffBits);
};

void printImageHeader(BMPIMAGEHEADER imageHeader) {
   printf("\nSize of header: %d.\n", imageHeader.biSize);
   printf("Width: %d.\n", imageHeader.biWidth);
   printf("Height: %d.\n", imageHeader.biHeight);
   printf("Color Planes: %d.\n", imageHeader.biPlanes);
   printf("Bits per Pixel: %d.\n", imageHeader.biBitCount);
   printf("Compression: %d.\n", imageHeader.biCompression);
   printf("Image size: %d.\n", imageHeader.biSizeImage);
   printf("Preferred resolution in pixels per meter (X-Y): %d-%d.\n", imageHeader.biXPelsPerMeter, imageHeader.biYPelPerMeter);
   printf("Number color map: %d.\n", imageHeader.biClrUsed);
   printf("Number of significant colors: %d.\n", imageHeader.biClrImportant);
}
```

Main function:

```
int main() {
   FILE *image;
   BMPFILEHEADER header;
   BMPIMAGEHEADER imageHeader;

   image = fopen("test.bmp", "rb");

   if(!image) {
      printf("Could not open the file %s.", "test.bmp");
      fclose(image);
      return 1;
   }

   fread(&header, sizeof(BMPFILEHEADER), 1,image);
   
   printf("File header information:");
   printFileHeader(header);

   if(header.bfType[0] != 'B' || header.bfType[1] != 'M') {
      printf("The file %s is not a valid BMP.", "test.bmp");
      return 1;
   }

   fread(&imageHeader, sizeof(BMPIMAGEHEADER), 1, image);
   
   printf("\nImage header information:");
   printImageHeader(imageHeader);

   if(imageHeader.biSize != 40 || imageHeader.biCompression != 0 || imageHeader.biBitCount != 24) {
      printf("The file %s is not a valid BMP.", "test.bmp");
      fclose(image);
      return 1;
   }

   fclose(image);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `sizeof(BMPFILEHEADER)` and `sizeof(BMPIMAGEHEADER)` on your compiler? According to the link you posted, it should be 14 and 40. If it is something different, then you likely have `struct` alignment or packing issues, which requires a compiler-specific remedy. In that case, please specify which compiler you are using.

Comment: The size of structs is ok. I change the bfOffBits to only int.

Comment: I have reverted your most recent edit, as fixing the error in your code invalidated the whole question (and also the answer). However, if you want to answer your own question, by pointing out the error, feel free to do so. See this official help page for further information: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure packing and alignment padding are implementation defined, and byte order is platform defined.

If the byte order for your platform is the same as that defined for BMP (little-endian) then you can use whatever compiler extensions your toolchain supports for structure packing.  For example in GCC:

```
typedef struct BmpFileHeader {
   char bfType[2];
   unsigned int bfSize;
   unsigned short int __bfReserved1;
   unsigned short int __bfReserved2;
   unsigned long int bfOffBits;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) BMPFILEHEADER; 

typedef struct BmpImageHeader {
   unsigned int biSize;
   int biWidth;
   int biHeight;
   unsigned short int biPlanes;
   unsigned short int biBitCount;
   unsigned int biCompression;
   unsigned int biSizeImage;
   int biXPelsPerMeter;
   int biYPelPerMeter;
   unsigned int biClrUsed;
   unsigned int biClrImportant;  
} __attribute__ ((packed)) BMPIMAGEHEADER;
```

Byte order for BMP is little-endian for for integer values; so for x86 and most ARM platforms you may not need to worry about byte-order.  Pixel byte order is somewhat less straightforward.

However for a truly portable solution you would have to read the data byte-by-byte and load each member of the structure individually - so called *deserialisation*.

You would also do well to ensure compliance with the header structure by using `stdint.h` data types `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `int32_t` etc.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problems. I also needed to change the long int in bfOffBits to only int.

Comment: @leandror : That is exactly why I recommended using the stdint.h types.  `long int` for example differs in width between 64-bit Linux, 32-bit Linux and  32/64-bit Windows.